# SQL spilt all rows into 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-structures

I have a SQL Server `.mdf` database and date-time is combined but I want split them from ' ' space.

I have date-time like this:

| Date-Time |
| --- |
| 2021-01-20 12:30:51.000 |
| 2021-01-12 12:23:46.000 |

I want to create 2 new columns and split `Date-Time` from ' ' space to these 2 new columns:

| Date-Time | Date | Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-20 12:30:51.000 | 2021-01-20 | 12:30:51.000 |
| 2021-01-12 12:23:46.000 | 2021-01-12 | 12:23:46.000 |

How can I do this in SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: `select cast([date-time] as date), cast([date-time] as time)` ?

Comment: Have you looked at the "working with dates and times" in sql-server docs?

Comment: `select "date-time", convert(date, "date-time"), convert(time, "date-time") from t` ?

Comment: Removed the mysql tag since it's unrelated.

Comment: What has your research show you? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
Select FORMAT([date-time], 'yyyy-MM-dd') AS[Date],
FORMAT([date-time], 'HH:mm:ss:m0') AS [Time]
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Why `FORMAT`? It's *terribly* slow compared to a non-CLR function like `CONVERT` (with a style code).

Comment: In scenarios requiring custom time formatting like HH:mm:ss:(3 digits in ms), the FORMAT function is more concise and direct compared to the workaround needed with CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME), 114).

Comment: That sounds like a ChatGPT reply.

Comment: My point was about performance, not character count.

Comment: Also, there's no need to `CAST` to a `time`.